# How can I measure total line length from dxf file in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocad

How can I measure total line length in dxf (AutoCad) file with Asp.net (C#)?

We need use this data for Laser Cut. 
We have like this UI
[measure total line length](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa1vC.png)

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can open the DXF file (it's a text file) and analyse it... but that's a lot of work and can be hard to debug.

There are some libraries for reading .DXF files, I honestly never used them, but you may try something line [.NET DXF Reader-Writer](https://netdxf.codeplex.com/).

Alternatively, I would suggest you use [AutoCAD I/O webservice](https://developer.autodesk.com/api/autocadio/v2/): you can upload your .DXF file, open and extract all line/geometry information that you need via C# (using a in-process custom plugin that you can load on the webservice). I believe this [github repository](https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/workflow-aspdotnet-autocad.io) should help you get started.